# String's lifetime when returning Vec<&str>

Tags: string, vector, rust, lifetime

Simple code:

```
fn foo() -> Vec<&'static str> {

    let mut vec = Vec::new();
    let mut string = String::new();

    // doing something with string...

    vec.push(string.as_str());

    return vector; // error here: string doesn't live long enough
}
```

I have problem that I need to process with string and return it in `Vec` as str. Problem is that binding string doesn't live long enough, since it goes out of scope after foo. I am confused and I don't really know how to solve that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `&'static str` is a string literal e.g. `let a : &'static str = "hello world"`. It exists throughout the lifetime of the application.

If you're creating a new `String`, then that string is not static!

Simply return a vector of `String`.

```
fn foo() -> Vec<String> {

    let mut vec = Vec::new();
    let mut string = String::new();

    // doing something with string...

    vec.push(string);

    return vec;
}

fn main() {
    foo();
}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you, changing String to str helped, so str has same methods as String? Am I right?

Comment: @RišoBaláž, it's more like that `String` has the same methods as `str` and more, because there is a `Deref<Target=str>` implementation for `String`. See [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/strings.html) (at the bottom) and [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/deref-coercions.html).

Comment: Idiomatically, you wouldn't use `return vec`, you'd just end the method with `vec`.